# Web comic about a girl with a tarantula that would scare her brother and finds out she's a demon

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

When I was in middle school (2014- 2015 ish), I would read this web comic that was absolutely fantastic. I remember it being well written and having a nice art style. It was in a more cartoon-y style- kind of reminding me of *Ava’s Demon*.

It’s about this girl, a teenager I assume, who wore a hat and a long coat, and has a pet tarantula. She often scared her younger brother in the beginning of the series with said spider- and thus got grounded a lot. When she sneaks out to meet a friend of hers, she discovers that said friend is a demon, and her whole world is turned upside down.

Later in the series she meets lots of different characters, including a boy with orange eyes(?) who turns into a seagull, a set of characters at a circus (where a large battle is played out), a man who can turn into some kind of a weapon (though if my memory serves right, I think he was damaged.) and many other demons- including some powerful one(s?). They wanted her for some purpose- maybe she was one of them? And if she didn’t join them, they would kill her.

You find out her family is part of some group that fights these demons, and that they adopted her to try and protect her- and everyone else, of what could happen if the demons got a hold of her and had a spell put over the house. She returned home- now able to see the protective barrier- but I can’t remember the rest.

Usually it updated pretty often and had lots of panels. I remember I used to read it on tapastic.